# ¿Hace la presencia de "como" necesariamente prescindible el predicativo pronominal en esta oración?

Tags: sintaxis

A raíz de un comentario que escribí en este foro, se me generó una duda de sintaxis. El comentario decía:

> Si en el intercambio de comentarios se genera una sana discusión, como creo que **lo** es ésta -- al menos hasta ahora --, personalmente no le veo objeción alguna.

Sin duda que es correcto decir:

> Si en el intercambio de comentarios se genera una sana discusión, como creo que es ésta -- al menos hasta ahora --, personalmente no le veo objeción alguna.

Tal vez ese "lo" sea redundante, pero ¿es necesariamente incorrecto o indeseable? ¿Qué opináis/opinan?

Answer (score 2):

Me da la impresión de que *lo* no puede referir a *una sana discusión*. Diferente sería el caso si tu comentario comenzase por

> Si en el intercambio de comentarios se genera una discusión y dicha discusión es sana…

porque allí *lo* referiría al hecho de que *dicha discusión es sana*. Tal es el uso que siempre le he dado yo y que siempre he leído como correcto al *lo* en estas circunstancias, aunque por otro lado tu comentario original no me haría detener la lectura y pensar dos veces.

Comment: @ pablodf76, gracias por tu respuesta. La realidad es que ese "lo" reemplaza al predicativo "sana": Esta discusión es sana. Esta otra no LO es. "como" es una conjunción muy particular, que tiene algo de pronombre relativo, similar al "as" en inglés. Mi pregunta apuntaba a si ese "como" refiere necesariamente a "sana", en cuyo caso "lo" estaría de más. Reconozco que es un tema sintáctico complejo, por esa ambigüedad del "como" que mencionaba. Es bueno saber que, al menos, no te "hace ruido".